# Remove prefix from a list of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How can I remove a sub-string (a prefix) from a array of string elements? (remove the sub string from each element)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using `RegExp` and `^` to ensure it is the prefix and not just somewhere in the string:

```
var arr = ['a1', 'a2', 'a54a'];
for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/^a/, '');
}
arr; // '1,2,54a' removing the 'a' at the begining
```

Answer (score 22):

```
function trimPrefix(str, prefix) {
    if (str.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return str.slice(prefix.length)
    } else {
        return str
    }
}

var prefix = "DynamicPrefix"
trimPrefix("DynamicPrefix other content", prefix)
```

Answer (score 15):

Many of the answers already given are wrong, because they'll remove the target string from anywhere in each of the elements (not just the beginning). Here's another approach:

```
var str = "str_";
["str_one", "str_two_str_", "str_three"].map(function(el) {
    return el.replace(new RegExp("^" + str), '');
});
```

Result:

```
["one", "two_str_", "three"]
```

Or, if you prefer simple iteration (with no higher-order function):

```
var str = "str_";
var list = ["str_one", "str_two_str_", "str_three"];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i] = list[i].replace(new RegExp("^" + str), '');
```

Comment: Only beef with this is that you're instantiating a new RegExp every time the function is hit.  At least in other languages this is expensive.

Comment: The number of answers on this question by 10k plus SOs is awesome.

Answer (score 8):

```
var pre = 'prefix_';

my_arr = my_arr.map(function(v){ return v.slice(pre.length); });
```

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if full browser support for `.map()` is needed.

you can also use `.forEach()` if you need to keep the original array.

```
var pre = 'prefix_';

my_arr.forEach(function(v,i){ my_arr[i] = v.slice(pre.length); });
```

Comment: This solution strips the prefix of array strings by length of `pre` regardless of whether it matches the prefix of the strings in the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(substr, '');
```

Example:

```
var arr = ['test1', '2test', '3test3'];

// Use only one of these lines
var substr = 'test';  // This is for substrings
var substr = /^test/; // This is for prefixes only

var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(substr, '');

console.log(arr); // Prints ["1", "2", "33"] to console
```

Comment: The OP request a prefix though, your code currently will replace it anywhere in the string

Comment: She asked 'Remove prefix from a list of strings'

Comment: Title says one thing, body an other.

Comment: Oh I see, in the title... Well in that case just change the value of substr from `'test'` to `/^test/`. Then it prints `["1", "2test", "3test3"]` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just for some variety:

```
substr = new RegExp('(^|\|)prefix_', 'g');
arr = arr.join('|').replace(substr, '').split('|')
```

*edit* - to show how you can limit to just the prefix with the right regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate on your list of string (with a for loop for example) and use the `replace` method ([details here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp))

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through them?

```
var list = ["foo", "bar", "meh"];
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i] = list[i].substr(1, 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DcvE2/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery `map` function -

```
var arr = $.map(['a1', 'a2'],function (s) {
    return s.replace(/^a/,'');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Gu82J/):

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i in element){
 str = element[i].innerHTML;
 str = str.replace(/^pre_/,'');
 element[i].innerHTML = str;
}
```